# What do UML diagrams have to do with scrum methodology?

Tags: uml, scrum

I'm working on the conception of a project using the scrum (i.e. Agile) methodology, and I wanted to know what UML diagrams do for this kind of methodology.

After doing some research, I found that the use case and sequence diagrams can be useful, but what else? Should I do these diagrams for the whole project, or iteration by iteration?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to programming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UML is an object modelling tool to better express different aspects of your product/project to stakeholders like developers , designers, clients etc. It is not much to do with the project management approach. You can follow Agile or normal waterfall model and still use UML.

But as Agile is iterative approach which keep on evolving so it makes sense to keep your UML docs updated to better take care of changes. So your UML diagrams will be created for each iteration. And as project evolves so are your UML diagrams.

> Typically UML diagrams which are useful are : Usecase diagram, Class diagram, sequence diagram, activity diagram.

Comment: I'd add to that list also package and component diagrams

Comment: is that doable in an android project?

Comment: yeah; you can do it for Android as well.